# Omit partial of a type to split that type into two parts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make an `extendProps` function that will:

- take a React component and partial of its props
- return a new React component that doesn't require those props provided to it already

#### Example

```
type Props = { first: string; second: string; third: string };

const ExampleComponent = ({ first, second, third }: Props) => (
  <div>
    <span>{first}</span>
    <span>{second}</span>
    <span>{third}</span>
  </div>
);

// Sets the "first" prop to "FIRST"
const ExtendedComponent = extendProps(ExampleComponent, {first: 'FIRST'});
<ExtendedComponent second="SECOND" third="THIRD" />;
```

Making this work with generics has been pretty tricky and I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function extendProps<P extends object, E extends Partial<P>>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
  extendedProps: E,
) {
  return (remainingProps: Omit<P, keyof E>) =>
    <Component {...remainingProps} {...extendedProps} />;
}
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors:

```
App.tsx:35:35 - error TS2344: Type 'keyof E' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof P'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof P'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof P'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        Type 'keyof E' is not assignable to type 'never'.
          Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'never'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

35   return (remainingProps: Omit<P, keyof E>) => <Component {...remainingProps} {...extendedProps} />;
                                     ~~~~~~~

App.tsx:35:49 - error TS2322: Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Partial<P>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
    Type 'Partial<P>' is not assignable to type 'P'.
      Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'P'.
        Type 'Partial<P>' is not assignable to type 'P'.

35   return (remainingProps: Omit<P, keyof E>) => <Component {...remainingProps} {...extendedProps} />;
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

[Here is a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ReactComponentType%3CP%3E%20%3D%20(props%3A%20P)%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0Atype%20Component%3CP%3E%20%3D%20(props%3A%20P)%20%3D%3E%20null%0Atype%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Afunction%20extendProps%3CP%20extends%20object%2C%20E%20extends%20Partial%3CP%3E%3E(%0A%20%20Component%3A%20ReactComponentType%3CP%3E%2C%0A%20%20extendedProps%3A%20E%2C%0A)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20(remainingProps%3A%20Omit%3CP%2C%20keyof%20E%3E)%20%3D%3E%20Component(%20%7B...remainingProps%2C%20...extendedProps%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A). (had to make some mock types to make it work there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type ReactComponentType<P> = (props: P) => null;
type Component<P> = (props: P) => null
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function extendProps<P extends Record<string | number | symbol, any>, E extends Partial<P>>(
  Component: ReactComponentType<P>,
  extendedProps: E,
) {
  return (remainingProps: Omit<P, keyof E>) => Component( {...remainingProps, ...extendedProps} as P);
}

type Props = { first: string; second: string; third: string };

const ExampleComponent = ({ first, second, third }: Props) => null

// Sets the "first" prop to "FIRST"
const ExtendedComponent = extendProps(ExampleComponent, {first: 'FIRST'});
ExtendedComponent({ second: 'SECOND', third: 'THIRD' })
```